# Get data based on day and month from mysql date field

Tags: php, mysql

I have a mysql table employees with a column 'Date_of_joining'. I am trying to get the list of employees whose date of joining is closest to the current date

Employees :

```
EmpID Date_of_joining 
1     2015-08-30
2     2019-01-15 
3     2018-01-11
```

Expected Result (assuming the current is today ie, 2023-01-09)

```
EmpID Date_of_joining 
3     2018-01-11
2     2019-01-15 
1     2015-08-30
```

I am basically trying to find who is approaching their work anniversary. Any clue or help is appreciated

**Edit :**

The below query works exactly like I want, but i also want to get similar data between two dates, is there way to achieve this using the same query or any tweak to it

```
SELECT *, (366 + DAYOFYEAR(Date_of_joining ) - DAYOFYEAR(NOW())) % 366 as left_days FROM employees ORDER BY left_days
```

Comment: What query have you tried so far? The current date format does seem to be "sortable" through the built-in MySQL query functions. Otherwise, just grab them all in PHP and sort them post-query. I'd break the date down with `strtotime` and sort via a simple array sorting function but that's one of many.

Comment: I have tried this : SELECT * FROM employees ORDER BY ABS(DATEDIFF(NOW(), `Date_of_joining`))

Comment: This sorts the date from month-day-part: `SELECT * FROM employees ORDER BY SUBSTRING(Date_of_joining, 6) ASC`;

Comment: And if you use this query `SELECT *,DATEDIFF(NOW(), Date_of_joining) as 'nbDays' FROM employees ORDER BY ABS(DATEDIFF(NOW(), Date_of_joining))`...?

Comment: @Juan Two things: The `ABS()` sounds strange. It will convert negative values to positive, i.e. if a birthday happened yesterday it will come first in the sort order. Secondly, you should add `WHERE nbDays >= 0` and user `ORDER BY nbDays` I guess

Comment: @Gowire You're right, but I assumed that no employees joined the company after today's date. With this query It may be better : `SELECT *,DATEDIFF(NOW(), Date_of_joining) as 'nbDays' FROM employees where Date_of_joining<=NOW() ORDER BY nbDays `

Answer (score 2):

You want to calculate and order by the upcoming anniversary date for each row.  This is simply:

```
case
    when Date_of_joining + interval year(current_date) - year(Date_of_joining) year < current_date then
       Date_of_joining + interval year(current_date) + 1 - year(Date_of_joining) year
    else
       Date_of_joining + interval year(current_date) - year(Date_of_joining) year
end
```

(treating anniversaries of Feb 29 in a non-leap year as Feb 28)

Comment: This didn't gave me correct results. see screenshot : https://ibb.co/tDhbBCk. Emp_ID 14's DOJ is closest to current date, so he should have come on top

Comment: it works for me: https://dbfiddle.uk/HMZtUkjU   show exactly what you are trying

Answer (score 0):

Two functions will help here.
`DAYOFYEAR(d)` returns the day number of the year for the date `d`. For example, because there are 31 days in Jan, we'd expect `DAYOFYEAR('2022-02-01')` to return `32`.

Next, `CURDATE()` returns the date for today.

The anniversary of date of joining is always going to be `DAYOFYEAR(Date_of_joining)`. So the number of days between today and date of joining is `DAYOFYEAR(CURDATE()) - DAYOFYEAR(Date_of_joining)` which you can add to a `where` clause.

```
select <choose_a_column>, DAYOFYEAR(CURDATE()) - DAYOFYEAR(Date_of_joining) as delta
from my_table
where delta > 0 # anniversary has passed
and delta < 10 # choose the number yourself
```

Comment: Nice solution! But, there's a special case when this won't work... It's when the current date is late in December. It won't find any upcoming anniversaries next year :)

Comment: dayofyear, in addition to not dealing with anniversaries upcoming in the next calendar year, will have odd interactions with leap years (considering an anniversary already passed when it shouldn't or being a day off)

Answer (score 0):

I know the query in my answer is complex but I'm posting it anyway if it helps.
It allows not only to have the anniversary date but also the number of days before the anniversary.

On the other hand I had to duplicate the code for obtaining the anniversary date to obtain the number of days, I don't know if there is a better way to do it.

```
select *, 
if(date_format(Date_of_joining,'%m%d')<date_format(now(),'%m%d'),concat((year(current_date)+1),date_format(Date_of_joining,'-%m-%d')),concat((year(current_date)),date_format(Date_of_joining,'-%m-%d'))) as 'anniversary',
DATEDIFF(if(date_format(Date_of_joining,'%m%d')<date_format(now(),'%m%d'),concat((year(current_date)+1),date_format(Date_of_joining,'-%m-%d')),concat((year(current_date)),date_format(Date_of_joining,'-%m-%d'))),NOW()) as 'nbDays' 
from employees 
order by anniversary
```